# Schemas installed with extension orafce on PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, orafce

I installed orafce extension on PostgreSQL 9.5. I saw that it is better to create a specific schema for all extensions and that what I did. I connected to template 1 and performed the next commands :

```
template1=# create schema extensions;
CREATE SCHEMA
template1=# grant usage on schema extensions to public;
GRANT
template1=# grant execute on all functions in schema extensions to public;
GRANT
template1=# alter default privileges in schema extensions grant execute on             
functions to public;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
template1=# alter default privileges in schema extensions grant usage on     
types to public;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
template1=# create extension orafce schema extensions;
CREATE EXTENSION
template1=# show search_path;
search_path
 -----------------
"$user", public
(1 row)

template1=# set search_path="$user",public,extensions;
SET
```

After that I created a new database test1 and a new user mariel1. In addition I edited postgresql.conf and set the search_path to be "$user",public,extensions.

I connected to the database - `psql -d test1 -U mariel1`. Now when I try to use the function sysdate for example the database doesn't recognize the function:

```
postgres=# select sysdate() from dual;
ERROR:  function sysdate() does not exist
LINE 1: select sysdate() from dual;
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need     
to add explicit type casts.
postgres=# select extensions.sysdate() from dual;
ERROR:  schema "extensions" does not exist
LINE 1: select extensions.sysdate() from dual;
```

After some searching I saw that some of the functions available under other schemas like oracle, utl_file and more. I want to understand why the functions of orafce (oracle.sysdate etc...) created under different schemas (oracle,utl_file..) and not under my new schema extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Extension in PostgreSQL is **Database** level not schema level or instance level. You cannot create same Extension in same database. But you can create same extension in multiple databases. that's how extension in PostgreSQL work.

Comment: I created the extension in tempalte 1 which means it will be created in every database that i will create. My question is why isnt the extension installed in the schema that i specify but in more schemas ?

Comment: can i know what "\dx" output in template1 database and others database?

Comment: template1=# \dx
                                                  List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                                          Description

---------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---
 orafce  | 3.6     | extensions | Functions and operators that emulate a subset of functions and packages from the Oracle RDB
MS
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language

Comment: okay i see it, your extension installed in extensions schema. can you show me "\dx" the other database ?

Comment: comb=# \dx
                                                  List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                                          Description

---------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---
 orafce  | 3.6     | extensions | Functions and operators that emulate a subset of functions and packages from the Oracle RDB
MS
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 rows)

Comment: Okay under database comb  and template1. can you show me "\dn" output

Comment: comb=# \dn
          List of schemas
          Name          |  Owner
------------------------+----------
 bl_create_flat_file_pg | repdev
 control_reports_pg     | repdev
 dbms_alert             | postgres , dbms_assert            | postgres, dbms_output            | postgres
 dbms_pipe              | postgres
 dbms_random            | postgres
 dbms_utility           | postgres
 extensions             | postgres
 oracle                 | postgres
 utl_file               | postgres

Comment: in comb i had 20 rows but i didnt have enough space (some schemas are specific for comb..)  template1=# \dn
     List of schemas
     Name     |  Owner
--------------+----------
 dbms_alert   | postgres
 dbms_assert  | postgres
 dbms_output  | postgres
 dbms_pipe    | postgres
 dbms_random  | postgres
 dbms_utility | postgres
 extensions   | postgres
 oracle       | postgres
 plunit       | postgres
 plvchr       | postgres
 plvdate      | postgres
 plvlex       | postgres
 plvstr       | postgres
 plvsubst     | postgres
 public       | postgres
 utl_file     | postgres

Comment: okay sir, i understand now? why your function created under because. when you execute "create extension orafce;"  you execute orafce.so already compile in source code orafce--3.4.3.SQL thats is the function creation. if you want all the function created under "extensions" schema you should change the source_code. because when you "create extension orafce" the orafce.so will create function basesd on the default source_code which is multiple schema